# Number of hits while crawling a website...?

Tags: python, web, web-crawler, urllib

I am creating a simple application where I have to follow links from a page and so on...thus building a very basic prototype of a web crawler.

When I was testing it, i came across robot.txt which has hits limit for any external crawlers trying to crawl their site. For example, if a website's robot.txt has a hit limit of not more than 1 hit per second (as that of wikipedia.org) from a given IP, and if I crawl few pages of Wikipedia at the rate of 1 page per second, then how do i estimate how many hits will it incur while i crawl?

**Question:** if i am downloading one entire page through the urllib of python, how many hits will it account to?

**Here is my Example Code:**

```
import urllib.request
opener = urllib.request.FancyURLopener({})
open_url = opener.open(a)
page = open_url.read()
print page
```

Comment: If your crawler limited to 1 hit per second runs for a minute, you will crawl less than 60 items (if your wait time between each is a second then processing and latency will add up and you'll probably achieve 55/minute). I'm not clear on what you are asking though - if you encounter links you will have to add them to a queue and process these at the rate of 1/sec too. Is your real problem that you want to know how long it will take to crawl Wikipedia at this rate?

Comment: i am sorry for not being clear...i have now edited my question to be more specific of what i am looking for...

Comment: If you download one page then that is one hit, unless your library also loads web assets like CSS, JavaScript, fonts and images (I presume the thrust of your question is about asset loading). Most crawlers don't fetch assets, since they are not of interest. Even if they did it would be hard to give a general answer, since it depends on the number of assets.

Comment: no, all i am extracting is the raw html (as seen from the view source) and not the assets like scripts and images...thanks for the information...

Comment: No problem. Out of interest, is there an encoding in `robots.txt` for a crawl rate? What does that look like, can you point me to one?

Comment: a robot.txt just states the rules for the crawler...i did not see any encoding for the crawl rate in it...but i guess the crawl rate by any given IP would be managed from their backend server scripts...this is what i was referring early today...
http://en.wikipedia.org/robots.txt

Comment: Right, it was this: "if a website's robot.txt has a hit limit of not more than 1 hit per second" that I was referring to. It seems to suggest the robots file is requesting a crawl limit `:)`.

Comment: "the crawl rate by any given IP would be managed from their backend server scripts" - or for high traffic cases it would be their front-end proxies, like Squid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you download an entire page from a site with `urllib`, it will account as one (1) hit.

Save the page into a variable, and work with this variable from now on.

Additionally, I'd advise you to use `requests` instead of `urllib`. Much easier/better/stronger.

Link to the [documentation of Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/).

Comment: i have added a sample code to my question...could you please verify if your response remains the same even after that? thanks...

Comment: it remains the same, as long as you keep on working with `page`

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do is put a time gap between two request , this will solve your problem and it also prevent you from get blocked.